# Class has no access to resources when both are inside jar

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, resources, illegalargumentexception

I've tried all sorts of combinations of code to try to access the resources to no avail. All of the code below works inside my IDE, but throws either a NullPointerException or InvalidArgumentException when executed from the Jar file.

```
//these don't work
//C3 = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("c3.png") );
//C3 = new ImageIcon( ImageIO.read( getClass().getResource("c3.png") );
//C3 = new ImageIcon( ImageIO.read( ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "c3.png" ) ) );
//C3 = new ImageIcon( ImageIO.read( getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "C3.png" ) ) );
//C3 = new ImageIcon(VP2CPConverter.class.getResource("/C3.png"));
//C3 = new ImageIcon( VP2CPConverter.class.getClassLoader().getResource( "C3.png" ) );
//
```

As a recent troubleshooting step, you'll see I moved all of the images to another folder, and changed the paths as you'll see in these images.

[image: executing jar]
[image: path to images]

The line the exception is pointing to is the one with "C3 = ...

As a previous troubleshooting step, I tried using getResourceAsStream() to list all of the resources that were available to see if it was only the one, but no resources showed up. It's as if they weren't there, but you can open up the jar and check the path and they are exactly where they should be.

Comment: Your images look to be possibly in the wrong place, but then your class files also look to be in the wrong place. Where are your packages?

Comment: This should work `C3 = new ImageIcon(VP2CPConverter.class.getResource("/images/c3.png"));`. Since `getResource` is case-sensitive for files inside of a jar-file.

Comment: @Edwardth I had no idea it was case sensitive! But my brain hurts now trying to figure out why getResourceAsStream() to list all available resources didn't show me my images. I would've figured it out right then and there! Btw, I didn't need the first forward slash before "images". Thanks so much! Write this as a formal answer and I'll let you have the answer for this one.